# Records not appending in a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I have a dataframe uuu_df with records as links of website

```
dim(uuu_df)
output
1950  1
```

uuu_df

```
1) http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs
2) http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs
3) http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=3&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs
.
.
.
1950) http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=>5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores
```

here I'm trying to scrape data using those multiple links from the dataframe along with the condition i.e. if the text of html attribute is equal to **"No Results Found!"** then skip that record and move on to next record,
this is the snippet of that scraping

```
UrlPage <- html("http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs")
ImgNode <- UrlPage %>% html_node("div.noResultHead")
u=ImgNode
u=as(u,"character")
u=paste("No",word(string = u, start = 4, end = 5),sep = " ")
```

Here is what I have tried

```
 wines=data.frame()
    url_test=c()
    UrlPage_test=c()
    u=c()
    ImgNode=c()

    for(i in 1:dim(uuu_df)[1]){

      url_test[i]=as.character(uuu_df[i,])
      UrlPage_test[i] <- html(url_test[i])
      ImgNode[i] <- UrlPage_test[i] %>% html_node("div.noResultHead")
      u[i]=ImgNode[i]
      u[i]=as(u[i],"character")
      u[i]=paste("No",word(string = u, start = 4, end = 5),sep = " ")

      if(u[i]=="No Results Found!") next
      {
        map_df(1:5, function(i) # here 1:5 is number of webpages of a website 
{

          # simple but effective progress indicator
          cat(".")

          pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_test, i))

          data.frame(wine=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".agentNameh")),
                     excerpt=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".postedOn")),
                     locality=html_text(html_nodes(pg,".localityFirst")),
                     society=html_text(html_nodes(pg,'.labValu .stop-propagation:nth-child(1)')),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

        }) -> wines

      }
```

But the Wines dataframe gives me empty dataframe with empty rows and columns
Why is it not able to append rows inside it.
Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance

P.S: dput() of reproduciable data

```
text1="http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom="
text2="1"
text3="&proptype="
text4="Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment"
text5="&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin="
text6="&BudgetMax="



bhk=c("1","2","3","4","5",">5")
budg_min=c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")
budg_max=c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")
eg <- expand.grid(bhk = bhk, budg_min = budg_min, budg_max = budg_max)
eg <- eg[as.integer(eg$budg_min) <= as.integer(eg$budg_max),]
uuu <- sprintf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", text1,eg[,1],text3,text4,text5,eg[,2],text6,eg[,3])
uuu_df=data.frame(Links=uuu)
dput(uuu_df)
```

Comment: I think you should be able to reproduce the subpart that is problematic, as you seem to say the downloading and "no result found" test work fine. If you give us `dput(pg) ` for a `pg` that is problematic we'll be able to help more easily.

Comment: Updated the post with reproducible data..kindly check..

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with one large list built using `lapply` that iterates through url column of dataframe instead of managing many smaller vectors:

```
urlList <- lapply(uuu_df[1,], function(url){     

    UrlPage <- html(as.character(url))
    ImgNode <- UrlPage %>% html_node("div.noResultHead")
    u <- paste("No", word(string = as(ImgNode, "character"), start=4, end=5), sep=" ")

    cat(".")        
    pg <- read_html(url)

    if(u!="No Results Found!") {
        df <- data.frame(wine=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".agentNameh")),
                         excerpt=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".postedOn")),
                         locality=html_text(html_nodes(pg,".localityFirst")),
                         society=html_text(html_nodes(pg,'.labValu .stop-propagation:nth-child(1)')),
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    } else {
        # ASSIGN EMPTY DATAFRAME (FOR CONSISTENT STRUCTURE)
        df <- data.frame(wine=c(), excerpt=c(), locality=c(), society=c())
    }
    # RETURN NAMED LIST
    return(list(UrlPage=UrlPage, ImgNode=ImgNode, u=u, df=df))    
})

# ROW BIND ONLY DATAFRAME ELEMENT FROM LIST
wines <- map_df(urlList, function(u) u$df)
```

Comment: your code is giving some error--> "Error: unexpected ')' in:
"    # ASSIGN EMPTY DATAFRAME (FOR CONSISTENT STRUCTURE)
    df <- data.frame(wine=()"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   # RETURN NAMED LIST
>   return(list(UrlPage=UrlPage, ImgNode=ImgNode, u=u, df=df))    
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> })
Error: unexpected '}' in "}""

Comment: And how does this line "df <- data.frame(wine=(), excerpt=(), locality=(), society=()))"  creates an empty data frame ,instead isn't it should be like --> "df <- data.frame(wine=data.frame(), excerpt=data.frame(), locality=data.frame(), society=data.frame())
"???

Comment: Whoops! See edit. There was an extra parenthesis at end and I correctly used the `c()` for empty vectors inside `data.frame` call.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the document tree to consistently find the elements you need and control the flow of the loop or vectorized function. In the example below I check the result count to determine if there are results, then parse each node individually to ensure it's consistent. Finally, you can bind them if needed.

Side Note: `llply` has the `.progress` argument which more elegantly handles the progress indicator you were trying to devise using `cat()`.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

uuu_df <- data.frame(x = c('http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs',
                           'http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs',
                           'http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=3&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=90-Lacs'))

urlList <- llply(uuu_df[,1], function(url){     

  this_pg <- read_html(url)

  results_count <- this_pg %>% 
    xml_find_first(".//span[@id='resultCount']") %>% 
    xml_text() %>%
    as.integer()

  if(results_count > 0){

    cards <- this_pg %>% 
      xml_find_all('//div[@class="SRCard"]')

    df <- ldply(cards, .fun=function(x){
      y <- data.frame(wine = x %>% xml_find_first('.//span[@class="agentNameh"]') %>% xml_text(),
                      excerpt = x %>% xml_find_first('.//div[@class="postedOn"]') %>% xml_text(),
                      locality = x %>% xml_find_first('.//span[@class="localityFirst"]') %>% xml_text(),
                      society = x %>% xml_find_first('.//div[@class="labValu"]') %>% xml_text() %>% gsub('\\n', '', .))
      return(y)
    })

  } else {
    df <- NULL
  }

  return(df)   
}, .progress = 'text')
names(urlList) <- uuu_df[,1]

bind_rows(urlList)
```

Comment: installed all the library you mentioned.

Comment: But still gives me error when I use my dataframe i.e " uuu_df " ---> "Error in if (results_count > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

> names(urlList) <- uuu_df[,1]
Error in names(urlList) <- uuu_df[, 1] : 
  'names' attribute [1950] must be the same length as the vector [3]"

Comment: And does this code extract data from multiple webpages of a website?